# Uploading images fail, other documents upload just fine

Tags: file-upload

When I upload any document to my SharePoint site, it uploads just fine.
I can upload using the website, SPD or WDAV.

However, when I try to upload a file with the extension .jpg .png and such the following happens.

Independent of the method I use to upload, after I hit the upload button it changes to the "processing" state and then after about 5 minutes it fails with a blank page. Stating that it can't load the page.

- Within SPD it just keeps "processing" the file.
- Using WDAV it eventually does "copy" the file or so it looks. I think it creates an empty file with . format, because I can't open the actual image file, after it uploads using WDAV.

I'm running SP2010 on Win2k8sp2

Do you have any idea how to fix this, or where to start looking?

Comment: Check restricted file types and also check whether do you have event receivers on Library.

Comment: Same issue here.The cause could be a security update installed in December 2014.

Comment: Exact same issue here. JPGs and PNGs just hang on Processing. Other file types are fine.
Have checked restricted files.
Haven't tried WDAV though. This is a new install, so haven't tried SPD either yet.
Any ideas which update Francesco?

Answer (score 1):

Please look here.It seems to be caused by a security update

> ### Symptoms
>
> We have seen a number of SharePoint issues caused by a recent Security Update KB 3013126 (MS14-085), including the following:
>
> 1. Unable to create Sites (Even with OOB templates except "Blank Site" template).
> 2. Image File Upload to picture libraries fails.
> 3. Content deployment hangs.
> 4. AspMenu does not function correctly (menu drop down does not work).
> 5. W3WP crashes with a stack overflow (it can hang too).
>
> ### Cause
>
> The issue appears to have been caused by an update to windowscodecs.dll (By Security Update KB 3013126).
>
> ### Resolution
>
> The current workaround is to either uninstall this KB 3013126 or update IE on the server to IE9 or IE10 (happens only if the
>   server has IE8) or install KB971512.
>
> It seems that there are some more prerequisites that are missing from
>   the security patch reference which gets covered by installing IE9\IE10
>   or installing KB971512.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2015/03/05/sharepoint-2010-unable-to-create-sites-or-upload-images-after-installing-kb3013126-ms14-085.aspx

The issue is the same using webdav and the pictures files are not restricted file types.